# Array histogram main

Tags: c, arrays, histogram

I'm working on this quite simple C program, wich builds an histogram from an array. What it does in particular, is writing on a second array the ciphres of the first array, followed by the number of their occurences. For instance: if the array A is {2,3,2,5,6,6,6}  the array histogram of A, will be {2,2,3,1,5,1,6,3}. Ok, so my program compiles well and there aren't any warnings or errors. But the program stops working after i' ve inserted the values of array A. Where am i failing??? Thank you!!

```
typedef unsigned short int boolean;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <conio.h>

boolean Array_Histogram(int *A, int N, int **H, int *count){
  int i,j;
  boolean found;
  *H = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int)*2*N );
  if(*H==NULL)
    return FALSE;
  (*count)=0;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    found=FALSE;
    j=0;
    while(found==FALSE && j<(*count)*2){
      if(A[i]==(*H[j]))
        found=TRUE;
      else j+=2;
    }
    if(found==TRUE){
      (*H)[j+1]++;
    }
    else{
      (*H)[j] = A[i];
      (*H)[j+1] = 1;
      (*count) ++;

    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}


int main(){

  int N;
  int count;
  int *A;
  int **H;
  int *i;

  i=0;
  printf("Inserisci N, dimensione dell'array A:");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  if(N<=0){

    return 0;
  }
  A= (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*N);
  *H = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int)*2*N );
  for(count=0;count<N;count++){
    printf("\n Inserisci il valore %d di A:", count);
    scanf("%d", &A[count]);
  }
  Array_Histogram(A,N,H,i);
  printf("\nI valori dell'istogramma sono:");
  for(count=0;count<2*N;count++)
    printf("\n %d", (*H)[count]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **INDENT** your code properly. I'm not going to read it as-is. Also.. `boolean`?! *If* you really want to define such a type (why?), use `bool` like pretty much every language besides java.

Comment: typedef unsigned short int boolean; is hilarious :D

Comment: boolean variables; and then comprare with TRUE and FALSE *grusel*. "if (found)" or "if (!found)" are much more readable

Comment: Sorry, but i wasn't able to indent my code. Apparently it's too difficult ._. However there is the problem. Debugging. As you may understand i'm not such an expert programmer, and noone really teached me how to debug. I'm using eclipse, but the there seems to be a problem with breakpoints.. they don't work as i expected. and in the variables list, at H, there's this message: Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression *(*(H))
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0x404008a1. I really can't find what this mean in internet.. CAn you help me??

Comment: who teaches these ugly "uppercase one-letter"-variable names?!?

Comment: never cast the result of malloc();

Comment: C allows you to use the space key! especailly around operators. It is much more readable (a courtesy to the reader)

Answer (score 1):

The variable H in main is of the wrong type. It should be declared:

```
int *H;
```

You need to change 2 more lines in main with regards to this:

```
H = malloc( sizeof(int)*2*N );
```

and

```
Array_Histogram(A,N,&H,i);
```

Also, you need to allocate H only once.

Comment: Also, `&H` should be passed to `ArrayHistogram`

Comment: @Magnus I added the two lines that need updating.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve but your problem is de-referencing `null` pointer.

`H` is double pointer to integer. so you have to allocate memory to `H` using `malloc` before using `*H`

```
int **H;
*H = malloc( sizeof(int)*2*N );
```

Edit:

Suggest you to read some basics about pointer [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html)

Comment: please, never cast the result of malloc();

Answer (score 0):

1. You are allocating memory for H twice(once in main, once in the func).
2. H is declared as int **, memory is being allocated to 2*N elements of integer pointers each, which is probably not what you wanted to do. 
   If you just want output as {2,2, 3,1..}, then probably you just want a int *H;